# How to know if an external URL is loaded successfully from the main process when using window.open() from the renderer process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, window-object, electron-react

Is it possible to identify whether an external URL is loaded successfully or not  from the main process, when `window.open("http://example.com")` is called from the renderer process?

Something like...

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('did-url-load', () => {
  // Do something
});

mainWindow.webContents.on('did-url-loading-failed', () => {
  // Do something
});
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out by creating a new **BrowserWindow** object to load the URL sent from the renderer process and then used the **loadURL** promise to identify whether the external URL is loaded successfully or not. I am not sure if anything simpler than this can be done.

```
mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
  const urlWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
  });
  urlWindow.maximize();
  urlWindow
    .loadURL(url)
    .then(() => {
      // Handle URL loaded successfully
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // Handle URL loading failed, like throw some error using dialog.showMessageBox
    });
  return {
    action: 'deny',
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have control over the page you'd like to open, you could use cross window communication methods. In the new window you hook into an events that fits your needs (onload?) and send a mesg over to the other window.

Maybe an Iframe also serves your needs?

Have a look at:
https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On MDN's [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) page:

> A WindowProxy object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the Window object representing the newly created window, and has all its features available. If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead null.

So, i think you should just check for the return value of window.open:

```
var dir = 'https://www.url.com';
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'main');

if (newWindow== null) {
  // Failed
} else {
  // Success
}
```

Comment: You can't use `return` as a variable name. Besides that this will not indicate if the page is succesfully loaded, only if a new tab has been able to open.

Comment: _"If the window couldn't be opened"_ means if the popup window itself could be opened, without getting caught in a popup blocker or similar issues. It has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with whether the assigned URL actually loads or not.